# insert php inside single and double qoutes

Tags: php, html

I have situation like this

```
header('Content-Disposition: attachment;filename="example_GGGG-MM-DD.xlsx"');
```

I have to insert the date in GGGG-MM-DD place. I have tried many things like using escape slashes,
separating into two parts, and using a function that adds backslashes. It always prints it as a string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/09dc231fc99a3f45610ca3945b26be8f3fcc616f

Use the dot concatenation

```
header('Content-Disposition: attachment;filename="example_'.$yourdate.'.xlsx"');
```

or swap quotes

```
header("Content-Disposition: attachment;filename='example_$yourdate.xlsx'");
```